# Silhouette chroma key effect - how to finish off?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I'm so close to finishing this off but I can't get my foreground to be single matte color. I'm not sure where I need to place a node to do so. My foreground right now has some aberrations coming through due to bad lighting but how can I make the white area a solid color? Thanks[image: ![Screenshot of my current nodes]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hoEms.png)

Comment: If you change the matte density by altering the luma values with a ramp or curve (change contrast) then you will alter the edge of your shape, loosing fine detail. I suggest that you add one to the other.

Answer (score 1):

After your Mix node you will want to add either a Luminance Key node, or a ColorRamp node. Then just move the values around until you get what you are looking for.

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]
or
[image]

I hope this helps

-Tom

Answer (score 0):

I hope I got your question right: You basically want a solid color mask, so instead of white, there should be a different color, right? If so, there's a simple way to go. As an example, let's have a look at a black & white mask:

[image: bw mask]

If now we want to give the white area a different color, we can use the MixRGB node to do so. You can find that in <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>  ->  `Color`  ->  `Mix`. Give the top color slot a black color, and the bottom slot the desired target matte color. Then, to mix the two together, you plug your black & white mask into the `Fac` slot of the node:

[image: finished comp]

This setup gives you freedom to choose foreground and background color as you wish. Also textures are possible, if you need that.